# How to get 'public_Profile' of the user from the Facebook access_token using OAuth2

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, oauth-2.0, facebook-login

I wanted to use facebook login in the app. I successfully get Facebook Accesstoken and even the user info {id:'###', name:'###'}. But I wanted the users Email and other public_Profile info to register his email and other details. How can I do that. Following is my code..Did my scope values are wrong? how can I get public_profile info, particularly email to register it in my app.

```js
const getFbToken = async (code) => {
  const tokenUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/v12.0/oauth/access_token";
  const queryValues = {
    code,
    client_id: FB_APP_ID,
    client_secret: FB_SECRET,
    redirect_uri: redirect_uri, // address must match with google redirect uri
    scope:"user_about_me,read_stream,publish_actions,user_birthday,offline_access,email",
  };

  const token = await axios
    .get(tokenUrl, {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      params:queryValues
    })
    .then((res) => {
    console.log('response', res.data)
      return res.data
  }
    ) // returns {{access_token, refresh_token, Authorization Bearer and id_token}}
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(`Failed to fetch auth tokens`, error.response.data);
    });
  console.log(token);
  return token;
};

const getFbUser = async (access_token, token_type) => {
  const fbUser = await axios
    .get(
      `https://graph.facebook.com/me`,
      {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${access_token}`,
          "Content-Type": "application/json",

        },
      }
    )
    .then((res) => res.data)
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(`Failed to fetch user`);
      throw new Error(error.message);
    });
    console.log('fbUser',fbUser)
  return fbUser;
```

Comment: You need to _ask_ for the fields you want, using the `fields` parameter. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/overview/#fields

Comment: I tried 'fields=id, first_name, last_name, email'....But it gives me all the above details except mail...Using FB test users, i find that we can get email address only when the user gives permission in his profile...can we get permission when we get consent from OAuth dialog box to the user?

Comment: You are already asking for the `email` permission in the `scope`, and that is all you can do. If the user's privacy settings generally prevent apps from accessing their email, then there is nothing you can do about that.

Comment: thank you very much